# Improving Flink broadcast performance

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I've a pipeline where I'm applying transformation rules(from broadcast state) on a stream of events; when I run broadcast stream and original stream in parallel without connecting, stream performance is really good, but the moment I do broadcast performance goes down drastically. How can I achieve better performance. Data passed between operators are in ***byte[]*** and data footprint is small as well.

I've attached snapshots of both scenarios:

1. Top row shows stream consuming events from Kafka and bottom row
   shows rules consumed from another topic. With this setup I could
   achieve throughput of upto ~20K msg/sec per task manager  processing
   12Gb of data in 4mins

[image]
2. I've connected the broadcast stream with the data stream for
processing in future . Note that only to measure performance of
broadcast I've made sure no records are consumed in the data
stream(top row). At the processing side of the broadcast state, i'm
only store received messages to MapState. With this setup I can get
throughput of upto ~1000 msg/sec per task manager processing 12Gb of
data in 18mins.
[image]

Comment: Could you please clarify if you have a sink in the 2. case? (it's cropped so I cannot see) How many elements do you broadcast?

Comment: Yes I've sink which tracks how many elements in broadcast missed in original stream . In broadcast stream I'm sending about 24 million records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've done more than simply connect the broadcast and keyed streams. Before, each event went through just one network shuffle (the rebalance, hash, and broadcast connections), and now there are four or five shuffles for each event.

Every shuffle is expensive. Try to reduce the number of times you change parallelism or use keyBy.

Comment: I've changed to make parallelism same across all operators and instead of broadcast I replaced it with connected streams.  With connected stream I was able to get similar throughput as in snapshot 1; only if there are no input data from main stream. As soon as data starts flowing in, throughput goes down similar to snapshot 2.